# If class is not present in table w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to remove a class from any place withing a table if another class is not found inside a span that is residing inside that table.

Basically I need to do the opposite of hasClass but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
if ($("#nyTable").find("span").not("ui-icon-triangle-1-s")) {
    $("#nyTable").find("td").removeClass("redText");
}

<table>
<tr>
    <td>as</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>werwe</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span class="ui-icon-triangle-1-s">asd</span></td>
    <td><span class="ui-icon-triangle-1-s">asd</span></td>
    <td><span class="ui-icon-triangle-1-s">asd</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE: I need to make sure that this class .ui-icon-triangle-1-s **does not exist anywhere in the table**.

Comment: anywhere in table or cell,and where's the class applied to?

Comment: Only remove .redText if .ui-icon-triangle-1-s does not exist at all in the table.

Comment: @santa: Isn't that what [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9647678/1106925) does?

Comment: I think a few answers on this page are correct -- the problem is with my code, I am afraid. I have another function that manipulates the classes. I don't get the class .redText removed until that function has run. I think I need to run additional check after all that's done.

Comment: Then execute the code after your first function is done .You can use something like `.promise().done(function() { your funtion here });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!$("#nyTable span.ui-icon-triangle-1-s").length) {
    $("#nyTable td.redText").removeClass("redText");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about somthing like this?

```
//$('#nyTable span:not('ui-icon-triangle-1-s')').removeclass('redText');

$('#nyTable span').not('ui-icon-triangle-1-s').removeclass('redText');
```

This is just "pseudocode" - this exact code will probably not work, but try something along these lines.

Answer (score -1):

Try it this way, you forgot your . for the class

```
if ($("#nyTable").find("span:not(.ui-icon-triangle-1-s)")) {
    $("#nyTable").find("td").removeClass("redText");
}
```